# Reduce execution time of rolling.apply(func) for large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, apply, rolling-computation

I start a thread for each df I have (approx size 500x10000).
The use of rolling.apply is very slow, I want to reduce the execution time.

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
     for value in myList:
          executor.submit(myFunc, value)
    
def myFunc(value):
     ...
     df[value].rolling(window=255).apply(ewm_std)
    
def ewm_std(x):
     # Custom implementation
     ...
```

It could be better if I use `pandas.core.window.EWM.std` or `pandas.ewmstd` instead of my implementation.

Comment: You could try [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel)

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use `df[value].ewm(appropriate_params).std()`?

Comment: I have to use the rolling function